# Power a MOC3010 with an arduino

Tags: arduino, power, triac

I have a project I am building for my Kids Church Room.  I have a bunch of LEDs being lit by an arduino Uno, but at one point in the light pattern, I want to have a bell ring. I bought a doorbell that comes with a 24v A/C transformer.  I have a few MOC3010 TRIAC chips from a previous build (that did not work..) from a few years back, so I thought I might use them.  If I use the arduino to trigger the Triac, which would activate the 24v, and have it turn off very quickly as part of the sketch, I think it would create the proper feel.
My question is does the output pin on an arduino uno put out enough power to make the TRIAC work.  My previous failed project LOOKED good, but the 7474 IC chips did not put out enough power to activate the TRIAC.  Anyone know???

Comment: You could have just looked up the datasheets, like you made me do. TI's MOC3010 datasheet says that \$8\:\textrm{mA}\$ is typically needed, with a maximum requirement of \$15\:\textrm{mA}\$ for the drive. So if you set things up for \$20\:\textrm{mA}\$, then I think you've got your bases covered there. I think the Arduino outputs (though it varies, given the large variety of specific devices in that category) can handle that much. But you should verify it with the exact board you have. If not, you could consider combining two outputs, I suppose. (The 7474, as you know, can't come close.)

Comment: I did pull up the data sheet, but I have VERY little understanding of how or why components work. I can take a schematic, assemble it,plug it in, and away we go.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Sadly your MOC3010 might not be up to the job. The [datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/moc3010.pdf) shows that the Triac current is an absolute maximum of 100 mA RMS. Most basic doorbells can draw much more than this on the 24 V AC side.
If you have a multimeter, you can test the current drawn by the doorbell, and if it's less than 100 mA by a good margin (say only 50-60 mA AC) then it may work.

The maximum LED Diode drive in the datasheet is 15 mA which is in range of the Arduino pin drive (20 mA) so the series R would be 270 Ohm for a 5 V Arduino (and 139 Ohm for a 3.3 V Arduino).

The project hangs on the 24 V AC current drawn by your bell.

You will notice in the datasheet that the MOC 3010 is usually used to drive a more powerful Triac, you could certainly do that to handle a higher current on the 24 V AC side.

**Now I hesitate to mention this** as this means you working with much higher voltages. You could switch the 110-120 VAC side of the doorbell transformer to achieve the same result. The MOC3010 would be able to handle this and the AC current likely is less than 50 mA; and even allowing for any surge the Triac has acceptable ratings.
If you are confident doing this then that may be a solution.....if you lack the confidence then I'd suggest you buy a Arduino compatible SSR or relay board from the likes of SainSmart. Here's a link to [Amazon](https://www.amazon.com/SainSmart-101-70-100-2-Channel-Relay-Module) for a 2-channel relay, but there are endless devices SSR and relay modules like this.
Much safer......

Comment: I appreciate the help.  I actually tried to read the sheet, but I am a Kids Ministries pastor, so don't really understand the math.  If someone says plug A int B, I can do it any time.  Thank you.

Comment: Then I really suggest you buy an Arduino relay board and wire it to the 24 V side of your doorbell. ....good luck.

Comment: I ordered a couple of the Arduino relay shields.  Seemed safest way.  I will run the 24v A/C through the relay.  Thanks for the help.